# How to display a single result from stored procedure to view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a stored procedure `GetUserDetails` which accepts a unique `EID` and displays a single result which includes different columns `(FirstName, LastName, etc).`. I want it to display on the `Index's` view.

Here is my `Index` controller's code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Set Session["EID"] as string
    var SessionString = Convert.ToString(Session["EID"]);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
             var result = db_RIRO.sp_GetUserDetails(SessionString);
        }
        catch 
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You may pass the Object of your model Class(User in this case) to your return statement. like: Return View(model); and then in make the view a Strongly typed view by using @model .

Comment: I suggest perhaps you take the introductory MVC tutorial provided by Microsoft, it explains these kind of core basic concepts - e.g. about getting data into your model, then sending your model to your view, and displaying data from the model in your view.

Answer (score 1):

Get the result set's auto-generated `result`. In my question the `GetUserDetails` stored procedure has an auto-generated `GetUserDetails_Result`.

Assign to a variable and return it to a `View`:

```
sp_GetUserDetails_Result result = db_RIRO.sp_GetUserDetails(SessionString).FirstOrDefault();
return View(result);
```

On my view I've imported the `Model` class for the `GetUserDetails` result, in this case my `GetUserDetils_Result` class.

```
@model OnlineRIRO.Models.sp_GetUserDetails_Result
```

and then call the fields you want:

```
@Model.FirstName
```

Answer (score -1):

To pass data from model to view,
you can use:

1. ViewBag

   e.g. in controller you write `ViewBag.MyData = "Data";`
   and in view you just use `@ViewBag.MyData`
2. ViewData

   e.g. in controller you write `ViewData.MyData = "Data";`
   and in view you just use `@ViewData.MyData`
3. TempData

   e.g. in controller you write `TempData["MyData"] = "Data";`
   and in view you just use `@TempData["MyData"]`
4. Custom Model

   e.g. use your own model and pass it to view

Reference reading: http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2014/06/using-model-pass-data-asp-net-mvc.html

Comment: How do I get a column from the stored procedure result to `ViewBag`?

Comment: in controller you set the value `ViewBag.FirstName = result.FirstName;` and in view simply use `@ViewBag.FirstName`

Comment: Using ViewBag/ViewData/TempData is NOT the recommended way of doing this. Passing the actual model to the view is the correct way, that gives front end compile time intellisense and removed dynamic uncertainty.

Comment: I have provided all the available options in answer, in the comments OP asked how it can be done using `ViewBag`